# How to use purrr::map to sum nas for each dataframe in a list

Tags: r, purrr

I have a dataframe of air pollution stations, each with a code c, and measurements of pollutants nox, no2, pm10, pm25. For example:

```
kcl_data
+-----------------------+--------+---------+----------+-------+------+--+
|        date           |  nox   |  no2    |  pm10    | pm25  | code |  |
+-----------------------+--------+---------+----------+-------+------+--+
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00   |  18.5  |   14.6  |  11.4    |   9   |  BL0 |  |
| 2018-01-01 01:00:00   |  20.2  |  17.3   |   8.9    |  7.2  | BL0  |  |
| 2018-01-01 02:00:00   | 20.3   | 17.5    |   6.9    |  6    | BL0  |  |
| 2018-01-01 03:00:00   | na     | 17.3    |   5.6    |  1.5  | BL0  |  |
| 2018-01-01 04:00:00   | 14.3   | 12.9    |   na     |  4.9  | BL0  |  |
+-----------------------+--------+---------+----------+-------+------+--+
```

Each station records values for a number of different pollutants at different times, and I want to use purrr::map (or map_df) to return a dataframe with the number of nulls for each pollutant and station. The result should look something like this:

```
+--------+--------+---------+---------+------+--+
| nox_na | no2_na | pm10_na | pm25_na | code |  |
+--------+--------+---------+---------+------+--+
|      1 |      0 |       0 |       1 | BL0  |  |
|      0 |      2 |       0 |       0 | BQ7  |  |
|      3 |      0 |       0 |       6 | BZ2  |  |
+--------+--------+---------+---------+------+--+
```

The problem is that the function I have written is working more like ::map followed by ::reduce rather than ::map. Here's the code I've tried:

```
nas_by_code_and_pollutant <- function(c,p) {
  df_sub <- filter(kcl_data, code %in% c) %>% 
    select(p)
  sum_na <- map(df_sub, ~sum(is.na(.)))
  sum_na
}

# this seems to work OK for one code and one pollutant
nas_by_code_and_pollutant('BQ7','nox') # $nox [1] 240 

# Now I want to output a dataframe of station codes and the number of nas by pollutant 
result_df <- map_df(codes, ~nas_by_code_and_pollutant(.codes,'nox'))
result_df
```

However, result_df is summing the total nas across each code (like map and reduce) rather than producing a dataframe with a column of station codes and the number of nas by pollutant.

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
     nox
   <int>
1 274709
```

Presumably this could also be done quite simply using groupby(code) and summing the nas, but I would like to get the purrr way right. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, no, that was my original setup, it's just a single dataframe holding all the data. I did try map(.x, f) with x being a list of dataframes, each for a single code, but couldn't get that to work eithher

Comment: I would use `group_split` and then loop over the `list`.  Perhaps that helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a single dataset,

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
kcl_data %>%
      group_by(code) %>%
      summarise(across(nox:pm25, ~ sum(is.na(.))))
```

---

If we need to use `map`, then `split` the data with `group_split`

```
kcl_data %>%
     group_split(code) %>%
     map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
              summarise(code = first(code), across(nox:pm25, ~ sum(is.na(.)))))
```

---

If we have a `list` of `data.frames`, then we loop over the `list` with `map`

```
map(kcl_data_list, ~ .x %>% # // .x => individual dataset
             group_by(code) %>%
             summarise(across(nox:pm25, ~ sum(is.na(.))))
```

Comment: That was quick :-) In that case, if kcl_data was a list of dataframes, what does the .x refer to?

Comment: @LucieCBurgess that was my earlier code,.  In that case, the `.x` will be the single data.frame in each `list`.  then you just need the code from group_by from my first code block copy/paste

Comment: @LucieCBurgess in the second case, we are splitting the data into list of data.frames where each element is for a particular code.  then loop. over the list with `map` and here `.x` implies each list element for that 'code',  do the summarise across the columns as well as return the 'code' (because here don't have the group attribute

Comment: Hi @akrun, please can you repost the map solution using the list of dataframes, as it's disappeared? Thank you, super elegant answer. Sorry for the delay in my reply, kids have gone to bed now!

Comment: @LucieCBurgess i added that case.  If you need the output as a single dataset, use `map_dfr`

Comment: Great, I get it, thanks! Much appreciated (and lightning speed) :-) So basically .x refers to each element of the list that's being mapped over ... I think this important element of the syntax was not clear to me.